# BotFramework Configure Email

Tags: botframework

When configuring the email channel, i enter credentials of an office365 account and the submit credentials process just hangs. Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you faced a transient error. I just tried with my O365 account and it validated the credentials. Can you try again?

[image]